# unable to login after installing video card

Tags: login-screen

I have been using Ubuntu for a while. I changed the video card (to have multiple monitors) and after fumbling with it I obviously screwed up something. Net result Ubuntu boots fine but when I try to login to my account it just returns me to the login prompt after some flickering. Now if I login from any other account (my wife's for example) it works fine so something in my account is messed up. Is there any way to reset the "control" files on my account so things work again? Any help greatly appreciated
Cheers
Gino

Answer (score 0):

At login screen of your PC press 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

then login there with the login details and then do removing `~/.Xauthority` file with

```
rm ~/.Xauthority
```

then restart your PC .

I hope that's going to fix your issue.

Comment: `mv ~/.Xauthority ~/_Xauthority_OLD` seems more sane, making it possible to recover any special settings in there.